# Derivatives defined on a discrete state space

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, optimization, discrete-optimization, utility

Ive been looking at certain economic papers, and optimal control papers. They define a state variable, $\omega$, which follows a discrete time Markov Chain. Then they define a utility function U($\omega$) on this state space, and a consumption function (both continuous and concave with first and second derivatives.) To solve the Bellman type equation:

If $\mathcal{C}$ is the space of all feasible consumption strategies:

$\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\text{max}} \text{  } U(c(\omega_{0,i}))_t + \mathbb{E}[U(c(\omega_{i,j}))_{t+1}]$

subject to:

$c_{0, i}(t) + \mathbb{E}[c_{i,j} (t+1)] = \omega$

by taking derivatives with respect to $c(\omega_{0, i})$ and $c(\omega_{i,j})$. Does this make any sense at all? And if it does, does it correspond to the maximum for this bellman type equation?

Comment: Edited according to @Nameless comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike your description, in economics you usually determine $c_{0,i}$ and $c_{i,j}$, i.e., consumption. Then even if $\omega$ has some discrete distribution, the choice set for a given $\omega$ would be continuous: take any $c_{0,i}\in[0,\omega]$. In that case, the first order approach would make perfect sense, given that the utility functions are concave. Now, choosing $\omega$ in the above problem seems trivial: you always choose the largest element of $\omega\in\Omega$. The real problem is deciding how to spend the wealth $\omega$ over the two periods. So you should check again what the decision variable is: I would bet is it consumption rather than wealth.

However, if the max problem is really as you write, so that $\omega$ is choice variable and discrete, then the first order approach would not make sense (as you point out), unless the optimal choice always happens to be element of the discrete set or there are some further assumptions on, say, the utility function (e.g., so that the derivative is a distance measure from the optimal point, and the lowest absolute value of the derivative would be the optimal feasible choice, as would be the case for some quadratic function). But typically, if you have to choose from finitely many alternatives, and the marginal utility at none of these alternatives is zero (that would be the optimum), then you have to compare imperfect alternatives and marginal utilities only help you in special cases.

Comment: Youre right, it is consumption. So consumption is a continuous mapping to a discrete space? How do you construct that correctly?

Comment: Here's how I think it works: at some point $t$, the decision maker (DM) has wealth $\omega$. This is the state variable. Wealth may be exogenous or evolves according to some process. At time $t$, the DM knows $\omega$, and he chooses consumption this period and saves the rest for next period. Next period, there is some uncertainty (over $\omega_{t+1}$?), hence the E-operator. So the demand/consumption function is a mapping $C:[0,\omega]\to[0,\omega]$ which tells you which part of wealth is consumed now and which is saved. I think just the the $\omega$ process over time is discrete.

Comment: If we construct it like that, consumption would be like a step function right? For each realized $\omega$ you choose a consumption. So for each discretely realized $\omega$ you have a consumption, which is discrete.

Comment: Not necessarily: typically the demand function is defined/constructed for all $\omega\in[0,\bar{\omega}]$, where $\bar{\omega}$ is the largest possible realization of $\omega$. So the function can be continuous in $\omega$ (Berge's maximum theorem guarantees the demand function will be upper hemi-continuous in $\omega$). The demand function is like a plan: it gives you a consumption level for each value $\omega\in[0,\bar{\omega}]$. But since not every value in that set actually realizes, it is true that the actual consumption may be discontinuous, because wealth is discrete.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well this is standard economics; deriving demand functions should be explained in every microeconomics textbook. The above decision problem seems a bit macroish, so you might also find something useful in macroeconomics textbooks, typically with infinitely many future periods and a discount factor ("infinite horizon decision problem") instead of just two periods as in your case. Acemoglu: "Introduction to modern economic growth", ch. 5 and others work with suchs problems.

Comment: I looked at those, they dont seem to have a formal mathematical construction